# data filter using API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to create a filter definition using SOAP API following the below definition -
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/filterdefinition/

Facing error on the datafilter tag. Below is my SOAP envelop. How should I provide the value for data filter here? For e.g. (CountryCode = 'US')

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>UserName</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options></Options>
    <Objects xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:FilterDefinition">
        <CustomerKey>DataFilter-API</CustomerKey>
        <Name>DataFilter-API</Name>
        <DataSource xsi:type="DataExtension">
                    <CustomerKey>AF4E965C-EC35-4BB7-B16F-1A41BA086C19</CustomerKey>
        </DataSource>
        <DataFilter></DataFilter>
    </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
<DataFilter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
   <Property>CountryCode </Property>
   <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
   <Value>US</Value>
</DataFilter>
```

If that does not work, please share what you have tried along with the error received.